# Where does the phrase "embedded in ira" come from (and what does it mean)?

Tags: story-identification

Back in the 1960s I read a science fiction book or story, probably by a prominent British science fiction writer like Brian W. Aldiss, where in the distant future the planet Earth had a ring.

This ring was composed of rubble from the Moon, which had exploded.  The Moon had been used as graveyard of abandoned spaces ships, and one of them "embedded in ira on the Moon", had exploded, destroying the Moon.

If the word "ira" was all lower case, ira would be some sort of condition or state, or maybe some type of material used to contain the spaceship, but I don't know of any word ira.

If "Ira" was capitalized, it would have been a proper noun, the name of a place on the Moon.  And I am not familiar with any place name of Ira on the Moon.

[This list of lunar features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_features) lists every example of each type of lunar feature in alphabetical order.  And there is no Ira on it.

So what story or novel am I thinking of, and what does "embedded in ira" mean?

added 04-29-2021:

In the English language "ire" is defined as strong anger:

> The bells were ringing in the Dale
>
> The Men looked up with faces pale.
>
> The dragon's ire, more fierce than fire,
>
> laid low their towers and houses frail."

In Latin *ira* or *irae* means anger or fury.

[https://www.latin-english.com/latin/ira/[2]](https://www.latin-english.com/latin/ira/%5B2%5D)

Comment: This feels very borderline “needs more focus” at the very least. Shouldn’t  the “embedded in ira” and story id be two separate questions?

Comment: https://dyn1.heritagestatic.com/lf?set=path%5B5%2F3%2F9%2F1%2F5391602%5D%2Csizedata%5B850x600%5D&call=url%5Bfile%3Aproduct.chain%5D

Comment: ira in Latin is 'anger'.  If 'in ira' was a phrase analogous to 'in situ', then perhaps the spaceship was deposited 'in anger', which it certainly was if it blew up the moon.

Comment: I think you should edit this post to emphasize the story identification. If you don't remember the story, then you may be misremembering the "embedded in ira" phrase.

Comment: If you haven't read it since the sixties, are you absolutely sure the word was "ira"?

Comment: I guess the key to this is identifying the story where an abandoned spaceship on the Moon blows up and destroys the Moon forming a ring of debris round the Earth. This seems more than sufficient info to identify the story, but I've been through my collection and I can find nothing that matches. Google isn't playing nicely either.

Comment: @gowenfawr It appears it also might mean Wrath in latin.

Comment: If it was a British author in the 60s, the suggestion might have been that the Irish Republican Army, known for bombings, had embedded a bomb in the ship.  Just throwing it out there, I feel like I'd have to read the story to make a better guess.